# Toggling full screen mode causes a black screen and a resolution change in Fortnite

Tags: technical-issues, pc, fortnite-battle-royale

When I go on *Fortnite* and press <kbd>FN</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> to go to full screen, my screen turns black for a few seconds, and then it goes full screen, but the resolution gets worse.

When I press <kbd>FN</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> to go back to the home screen, the screen goes black and the resolution goes back to normal, but not on full screen. I have updated my BIOS and drivers; I’ve even factory reset my PC.

Specs:

- Ryzen 5 5600X
- RTX 3060 12 GB
- 16 GB of RAM
- 1 TB of SSD
- Gigabyte B550M DS3H AC

Any idea what might help?

Comment: ... Just go settings, set it to full-screen and set whatever resolution you like?